# Get info from MySQL to display on items which are 14 days due

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP program that a user types in the last time they registered, they need to renew every year so I would like to display it for the admin to see 14 days before when the users are due to renew.

The structure is as follows:

```
join_date, members_name, members_address, members_telephone, members_email
```

I want them to be displayed, `join_date` is formatted as yyyy/mm/dd

The table it is stored in is called `customer_tbl`.

This is what I have so far as I am new I have tried.

```
SELECT customers_tbl.join_date
FROM
customers_tbl
WHERE
'DATEADD(dd, -14, GETDATE())' = customers_tbl.join_date
ORDER BY
customers_tbl.join_date
```

So for this all, I want is it to display people who's join date is due in 14 days time.

At the moment I am getting nothing displayed.

Thank you for anyone who looks at this and offers advice.

Second attempt still nothing

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

 include('includes/dbconn.php');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `customers_tbl`
 WHERE (
    MONTH('join_date') = MONTH(CURDATE())
    AND DAY('join_date') = DAY(CURDATE())
  ) OR (
    MONTH('join_date') = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY))
    AND DAY('join_date') = DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY))
  ) OR (
    MONTH('join_date') = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -28 DAY))
    AND DAY('join_date') = DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -28 DAY))
  )";


   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   $num_result = mysql_num_rows($result);
   if($num_result > 0){

   echo $result['join_date'];   
   }

   echo $result['join_date'];   


?>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Are you after a SELECT statement? If so, give it a go using your MySQL console or phpMyAdmin on your machine, and edit it into your question. Someone will be pleased to give you some assistance once you've given it a go.

Comment: Upvoted for the prior attempt - it's always good to add that `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you how to do it but I'm not going to program it for you, for the same reason as John Conde explained.

- Construct a database connection (I recommend using PDO).
- Init a sql query which selects all users where current date is equal to or greater than (join_date + 1 year - 14 days)
- Consider adding a column which is called expire_date, it will make it easier for you to check, but. you will have to decide the value when you insert a user.
- Create a div with a certain id.
- Use javascript (for example: the jQuery library) to perform an AJAX request to your backend (the one containing the pdo database connection and the query).
- Select all the users who match your search, and store it into an JSON array ($jsonArray), containing all the users who match the query you created.
- Return the JSON array to the javascript (echo json_encode($jsonArray); & flush();)
- Use the data from the json array to construct a table which you will use to appear into the div you created.

I could probably be more specific but that's something that we can discuss if you show some code.

Comment: Sorry John,halfer and Jonas, I never wanted anyone to write the program for me, I just need some direction as I have spent the weekend testing different SQL query's and after reading up on it, I just have gotten confused with all the different expressions used. So I apologise if I came across as an idiot, or came across lazy , as at teh moment I'm banging my head against a brick wall trying to get it to work.

Comment: Well, do my points help? You can also write code for sub problems and post them individually (individual questions) if you're having troubles with code.

Comment: Yes your points have helped I'm just strugling with even return a value, I have come up with the following but I get nothing displayed. I've added two queries to my question to see if anyone can help me with it.

Comment: To begin with, you should up vote if it is helpful, and now: I can tell you that you should stop using the mysql specific syntax since It's not supported anymore and it actually just sucks :P read about PDO (I've made a numerous posts which you can find in my profile). Now: Strip your queries down, if the sql is not working then you could start by doing some simple things like fetching the basic data, and make PHP do the work for you, it might be easier, a lot easier.

Comment: If you have more specific questions, then feel free to make new (clear and very specific) questions and copy the link to here so I can see it.

Comment: @PhpNewbie, no worries. Don't be put off by the apparently brusque responses you might receive here - we see a _lot_ of questions from people who haven't tried, and at StackOverflow we generally want to see prior attempts. Sounds like you've made a good effort beforehand, so the best thing you can do is show what _code_ you've tried, even if it's wrong - we like to see people give it a go. You'll get loads of specific help if you do!

Comment: Thank you halfer, it is okay, I understand how stupid my question must have seemed to everyone beofore I put the code up, as I'm sure it would annoy alot of people if they thought I had made no effort. I sort have worked it out on my own, but still having issues with it, but I keep trying until I get it right, at least I am learning loads which is a bonus, but thank you for your kind words Halfer.